# Asp.net MVC populate related fields from primary field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Using asp.net MVC, is there a best-practice approach to populating related fields asyncronously once a user as entered a primary key field.  eg, Once the user has entered EmployeeID on the form, the employeeName should populate if the entered EmployeeID is valid.

(I am already using the RemoteAttribute to validate that the entered EmployeeID is valid or not, and was hoping that this would be able to return related fields somehow, since it is already making the call to the repository.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery to call an async action passing the Id and fill on the result with the return, try something like

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#employeeId").change(function() {

         $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeData", "Employee")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { employeeId : $("#employeeId").val() },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success)
                {
                    // fill the employee name
                    $("#employeeName").val(data.employeeName);
                }
                else
                {
                    // show a message in a alert or div
                    alert('This Employee ID is not valid. Try again!');
                    $("#employeeId").text("").focus();
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
```

And in your action, try to create a post method to return the Name, or any property you need, just adding to Josn method return.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetEmployeeData(string employeeId)
{
    var employee = /* get your employee using employeeId parameter from Repository*/;
    if (employee != null)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true, employeeName = employee.Name });
    }
    return Json(new { success = false });
}
```

Comment: Thanks...works beautifully, though I had to change the method type to a GET instead of POST.

Answer (score 1):

No, the RemoteAttribute doesn't return data values, only validation information. The best practice here would be to use javascript / jquery / ajax. If you already have a form element wrapping your employee id textbox, you could have it submit when the validation succeeds. You can then use javascript to intercept that form submit and send an AJAX request to an action method on your controller which returns a JsonResult. When you receive the JSON in the browser, use it to populate the other fields.

**Reply to comments:**

Do not wrap it in a nested form. Having forms within forms is not valid HTML. If you are using this employee id to populate another form (another set of textboxes), yes, I would make them 2 separate (sibling) forms. Your JSON should also return the EmployeeID, and in the second form, I would place this in a hidden field rather than reusing the textbox for user input of the employee id.

Comment: Thanks Dan, was afraid it would be this number of steps.  So, that form you're talking about...the employeeID is indeed already wrapped in a form with a whole lotta other elements as well...you saying I can (should) wrap the employeeID in a nested form of its own, that contains only that one element?